# Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, testflight

I have this error
Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle

Trying to upload app on testflight

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu38L.png)

I was trying to archive and upload to testflight for testing
I created a provisioning profile and create new certificates

Comment: Please follow these steps : https://medium.com/readytowork-org/step-by-step-guide-on-generating-an-ios-certificate-preparing-for-test-flight-and-releasing-ios-99cd2eb11067